# Automatic casting from one object-class to another

Tags: java, class, casting

I have two Java-Classes as follows:

```
public class MyClass {
...
}

public class MyClassList extends ArrayList<MyClass> {
...
}
```

Now i have any method which takes `MyClassList` as a parameter. The method should also accept `MyClass` instead. I know that I could overload the method.

Is there any possibility to achieve the same result with only one method? I am thinking of method in `MyClass` which automatically gets called and casts itself to `MyClassList`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You would have to overload the method. You can't provide user-defined implicit conversions in Java.

Answer (score 1):

But `MyClassList` does not extend `MyClass`.

Your method will have to take an `Object` type if, for some reason, you want a single method to accept both `MyClass` and `MyClassList`.  Then you're going to have to do `instanceof` tests, if you want to work with their specific types (unless all you want do is call methods belonging to `Object`).

I think two separate methods is the best course of action here.